# Split 4 digit number into 2 variables in PHP

Tags: php

Using PHP...

If I have a number, for example, 0901, how can I then get 2 separate variables?

The first containing "09" and the second "01".

Thanks!

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve this... but you go first: what have you tried? If the response to that is "I tried posting on stackoverflow", you have not done enough on your own yet.

Comment: Is the length of the number always known ahead of time, even if it has leading zeroes? I.e., given `1`, the output would be `00` and `01`, and the number `10000` would never appear? Also, are these actual numbers (integers) or strings that just happen to contain numbers?

Comment: Is it always 4 digits? What happens if it is 3 or 5, how would you split it? What code attempts have you tried? What php functions have you tried? ie [`array str_split ( string $string [, int $split_length = 1 ] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str_split`. You can divide in half.

```
$number = "0901";
$arr = str_split($number, strlen($number)/2);

print $arr[0];
print $arr[1];
```